# How to use a custom SVG file in material ui SVG ICON

Tags: reactjs, svg, material-ui

I am trying to use a `chip` with SVG delete icon,

The icon code is

```
const icon = (props) => {
    return (
        <SvgIcon>
            <img src={'ic_check.svg'} style={{width: '20px'}} width={'20px'}/>
        </SvgIcon>
    )
};
```

The content of SVG file

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <rect width="20" height="20" x="2" y="2" fill="#6FB934" rx="10"/>
        <path fill="#FFF" fill-rule="nonzero" d="M9.5 15.475L6.025 12l-1.183 1.175L9.5 17.833l10-10-1.175-1.175z"/>
        <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

and the chip finally is

```
<Chip
      label={ViewUtils.NOT_EXPIRED}
      className={classes.chip}
      onDelete={() => {}}
      deleteIcon={<icon/>}/>
```

But this is not working and I checked for the path and it is correct as I can render same svg in `img` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nayan SvgIcon takes a svg path that you can further style. But in your case your svg is already styled. It doesn't take svg file directory path which actually lose SvgIcon API purpose.
You just need to remove `SvgIcon` from `img` tag:

```
<Chip
  label={ViewUtils.NOT_EXPIRED}
  className={classes.chip}
  onDelete={() => {console.log('You Deleted this icon')}}
  deleteIcon={icon}
 />
```

and Make you svg as const or import from assets file directory I haven't tried that,

```
const icon = <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
               <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
                <rect width="20" height="20" x="2" y="2" fill="#6FB934" rx="10"/>
                <path fill="#FFF" fill-rule="nonzero" d="M9.5 15.475L6.025 12l-1.183 1.175L9.5 17.833l10-10-1.175-1.175z"/>
                <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z"/>
             </g>
           </svg>
```

There is a reason why we can't make `<icon/>` component. If we make it as component as following:

```
const Icon = (props) => {
return (
<SvgIcon>
  <svg
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    width="24"
    height="24"
    viewBox="0 0 24 24"
  >
    <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
      <rect width="20" height="20" x="2" y="2" fill="#6FB934" rx="10" />
      <path
        fill="#FFF"
        fill-rule="nonzero"
        d="M9.5 15.475L6.025 12l-1.183 1.175L9.5 17.833l10-10-1.175-1.175z"
      />
      <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" />
    </g>
  </svg>
</SvgIcon>
)
};
```

It works like a charm but onDelete doesn't get fired on this component.I've reported this issue as well on material UI. In first case onDelete gets called every time. Feel free to ask any question.

**EDITED** Fixed the above issue for Icon as Component rather than const. here is the codesandbox link for working example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/98842r4yy4

Comment: hey, I tried using the `icon` constant in with `chip` but doesnt work from your answer, am I missing something?

Comment: Please paste your updated code here after adding constant.

Comment: const svg = <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <rect width="20" height="20" x="2" y="2" fill="#6FB934" rx="10"/>
        <path fill="#FFF" fill-rule="nonzero"
              d="M9.5 15.475L6.025 12l-1.183 1.175L9.5 17.833l10-10-1.175-1.175z"/>
        <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z"/>
    </g>
</svg>;

const icon = () => {
    return (<img src={svg}/>)
};

Comment: Ah, no. You were right, thanks. img tag works like a charm.

Comment: found your issue. <img> tag takes src as path. You need to give svg file directory path for example: /build/assets/icons/test.svg.

Second don't use Icon as component I gave explanation above. Use it like this:
 const Icon =<img src={'/build/icon/test.svg'} />;
that's the source in my case.  put svg in icon folder.

Answer (score 0):

I am using React and typescript, created a component and added the  tags from HTML and it worked normally.

```
export const IconTable: React.FC = () => {
    return (
        <svg width="130" height="130" viewBox="0 0 1024 1024">
            <path d="M505.947 123.597a23.096 23.096 0 0 0-16.99-7.477h-6.837c-17.929 0-32.631 13.468-34.198 "/>
        </svg>
);
```